# flex-direction:column justify-content not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I coded a html file that has a body element and in the body element there are 3 paragraph tags.

all the paragraphs have border of 2px solid black I want to collapse the borders of all paragraphs using flexbox. here is html and css code:

```
<body>
  <p>
    iisquam quis maxime laudantium, rerum saepe, eum, nam velit ipsam expedita sed nulluisquam minus ullam ducimus ipsam excepturi eligendi, harum similique perspiciatis provident accusamus suscipit! Hic doloribus inventore corrupti obcaecati praesentium maiores reiciendis consectetur pariatur veritatis quam saepe libero blanditiis fugiat, quae recusandae cumque. Delectus libero, nam accusamus mollitia quia deserunt?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, aut magnam? Iure nemo totam corporis in quos, nesciunt suscipit at reprehenderit pariatur cupiditate tempore iste error, ducimus ea eveniet aut ipsum id labore, quidem impedit nihil voluptate fugiat voluptatum explicabo. Iusto officia unde, nesciunt aliquam enim temporibus? Eaque, placeat dignissimos!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos autem exercitationem laborum illo ipsum ex corporis omnis. Rem dignissimos perspiciatis sequi quod officiis, reiciendis iste.
  </p>
</body>
<style>
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:stretch;
}
p{
  border:2px solid black;
  maring:0;
}
</style>
```

You can see that justify-content property is set to stretch. but in the output the pargraphs are not at all stretched. There is a space between each paragraph element and the borders are not collapsed. How can I fix the css code such that there is no margin like space around all the flex items

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: `stretch` is not a valid value for `justify-content`, so it's not at all clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the style of the `<p>` tag

Instead of:

```
maring:0;
```

use

```
margin:0px;
```

It's just a typo in your css definition.

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo in your css.

```
p{
  border:2px solid black;
  maring:0;
}
```

Change

```
maring: 0;
```

to

```
margin: 0;
```

and it should work.